# how to modify banner size in welcome screen of install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am just making an installer for Windows, Mac and Linux using install4j. However, it isn’t clear from the docs how to change the banner size on the left hand side.

However it changing size automatically with respect to image on banner but I need to change the size of banner of left hand size.

Is there any option available to modify banner size in welcome screen of install4j?

Comment: As you said, the width of the banner depends on the size of the supplied image. Why would you like to set a different width?

Comment: I want to utilize maximum space for text in remaining area.

Comment: Then you would need to make the image smaller, there is no other way to do that

Comment: Yes. That will be good solution.Many thanks Ingo.